# Synching Ethereum node - do I need to start geth seperately?

Tags: mining, wallets

I installed Ethereum 0.9.1 from Github on iMac running macOS 10.12.6. Synching 6 days now & still going. Documentation on all things Ethereum is garbled to say the least. Does anyone know if I now need to start geth seperately in a new command prompt ? What directory structure should I now have on hard disk? Whats the relationship between geth - Ethereum - mist ? Where EXACTLY does the geth exe reside? Is there a resource to answer what are really fundamental questions of installing Ethereum, getting mining up and running, connecting to Ethereum wallet - relationships between all the components?

Answer (score 0):

The explanations for installing on MAC/OSX is on the [github wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installation-Instructions-for-Mac) and general information is [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/README.md).

Also if you already have geth installed and run it from a terminal in OSX just include the --fast to sync more quickly and download only what is needed.  It's likely you are downloading an archival node which would take up over 200GB of storage.  Remove the .ethereum folder in your home directory and then restart with

```
geth account new
geth --fast --cache=512 console
```

Depending on your bandwidth it should take anywhere from a few hours to a full day to download.

Cheers

Comment: Followed the links and instructions there. Seems OK (syncing fine now). I have both a Mist.app & Ethereum Wallet.app installed on my iMac. Do I need to remove Mist ? and should I restart the Ethereum Wallet  whilst geth is syncing ?

Comment: UPDATE: seems to be pulling 200k blocks per day. Is this a reasonable amount ?